# How do I negate this definition of continuity?

Tags: logic, continuity, proof-writing

How would I negate this statement?

> A map $f : X \to Y$ is called continuous if, for any subset $A \subset X$ and any point $x \in X$ adherent to $A$, the point
> $f(x)$ adheres to $f$.

I've tried

> There exists $A \subset X$ and $x \in X$ adherent to $A$ such that $f(x)$ is not adherent to $f(A)$.

Comment: It looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Formally negation works as $\neg(\forall x \in X)(\forall y \in Y)(A \Rightarrow B) = (\exists x \in X)(\exists y \in Y)(A \land \neg B)$. So in your case having
$$(\forall A \subset X)(\forall x)(x\in X \land x\text{ adherent to }A \Rightarrow f(x) \text{ adhers to } f)$$
negation gives
$$(\exists A \subset X)(\exists x)(x\in X \land x\text{ adherent to }A \land f(x) \text{ not adhers to } f)$$